# Entity Framework: Navigational properties - Code First

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Man I am having a heck of a time today trying to get this to work.  I think I'm missing something in terms of a navigational property.

My controller.  When I put a breakpoint at foo = 5, and I look at the local watch window, "listOfComments" has zero elements even though my database has the information listed(see below)

```
public ActionResult CommentsList()
    {
        var post = _db.GetPost(5);
        List<Comment> listOfComments = post.Comments.ToList();
        var foo = 5;
        return View(post);
    }
```

GetPost method

```
public Post GetPost(int? postId)
    {
        var context = DataContext;

        var post = context.Posts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == postId);
        if (post == null)
        {
            return new Post();
        }
        return post;


    }
```

Comment class

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    //Navigational
    public Post Post { get; set; }

}
```

Post class

```
public class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
        Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
        Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    //Navigational

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

}
```

My DbContext class

```
public class HundredBlog: DbContext
{
    public HundredBlog() : base("HundredBlog") { }

    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }


}
```

The Database table, "Comments" has the following columns:

```
-Id
-Date
-Name
-Email
-Body
-Post_Id
```

The Database table, "Posts" has the following columns:

```
-Id
-Title
-Date
-Body
```

Just as an example, my Database populates the Comments columns just fine, it adds the right Post_Id referencing the primary key and all.  I have the same issue with the Tag table, but that even has it's own reference table:

The Database table, "TagPosts" has the following columns:

```
-TagId
-PostId
```

Lost please help!

Comment: I don't see the code for GetPost

Comment: just updated to reflect GetPost, i dont think thats an issue but should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Comments collection in the Post class should be virtual if you want to enable lazy loading or you should use `Include(p => p.Comments)` to load the data with the original query. In general the second option is better.

Comment: This worked for me.  I couldn't get lazy loading to work by making it virtual(it kept throwing an exception because of the new HashSet).  I coudln't get around it so in the LINQ query I just included comments with Include(x=>x.Comments).Include(y=>y.Tags)...etc

It worked.  Thanks Stilgar!